# @ComponentScan giving error. How to resolve?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I am learning spring and springboot and have created a project where I am using a configuration class to create beans.

I also have a pom.xml file where I add the dependencies.

The codes are as follows:

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

 <groupId>com.lcwd.withoutboot</groupId>
 <artifactId>SpringWithoutBoot</artifactId>
 <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>

 <name>SpringWithoutBoot</name>
 <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
  <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  <maven.compiler.source>20</maven.compiler.source>
  <maven.compiler.target>20</maven.compiler.target>
</properties>

<dependencies>
  <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-core -->
  <dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.24.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-context -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
  <version>5.2.24.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
```

AppConfig.java

```
package com.lcwd.withoutboot.config;

import com.lcwd.withoutboot.beans.CartService;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;

@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = {"com.lcwd.withoutboot"})
public class AppConfig {

    @Bean("cartService1")
    public CartService cartService(){
        return new CartService();
    }
}
```

App.java

```
package com.lcwd.withoutboot;

import com.lcwd.withoutboot.beans.CartService;
import com.lcwd.withoutboot.beans.UserService;
import com.lcwd.withoutboot.config.AppConfig;
import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        System.out.println( "Application Started" );
        ApplicationContext context=new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(AppConfig.class);
        CartService cartService=context.getBean("cartService1", CartService.class);
        cartService.createCart();

        //UserService userService=context.getBean(UserService.class);
        //userService.saveUser();
    }
}
```

The error I am getting is as follows:

```
Jun 01, 2023 12:56:58 PM org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext refresh
WARNING: Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\Users\soura\Desktop\SpringWithoutBoot\target\classes\com\lcwd\withoutboot\App.class]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [C:\Users\soura\Desktop\SpringWithoutBoot\target\classes\com\lcwd\withoutboot\App.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64
Exception in thread "main" org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Failed to read candidate component class: file [C:\Users\soura\Desktop\SpringWithoutBoot\target\classes\com\lcwd\withoutboot\App.class]; nested exception is org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [C:\Users\soura\Desktop\SpringWithoutBoot\target\classes\com\lcwd\withoutboot\App.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:457)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.findCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:316)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.doScan(ClassPathBeanDefinitionScanner.java:276)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScanAnnotationParser.parse(ComponentScanAnnotationParser.java:132)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.doProcessConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:296)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.processConfigurationClass(ConfigurationClassParser.java:250)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:207)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassParser.parse(ConfigurationClassParser.java:175)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.processConfigBeanDefinitions(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:320)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.postProcessBeanDefinitionRegistry(ConfigurationClassPostProcessor.java:237)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanDefinitionRegistryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:280)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:707)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:533)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.<init>(AnnotationConfigApplicationContext.java:89)
    at com.lcwd.withoutboot.App.main(App.java:18)
Caused by: org.springframework.core.NestedIOException: ASM ClassReader failed to parse class file - probably due to a new Java class file version that isn't supported yet: file [C:\Users\soura\Desktop\SpringWithoutBoot\target\classes\com\lcwd\withoutboot\App.class]; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:60)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.<init>(SimpleMetadataReader.java:49)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(SimpleMetadataReaderFactory.java:103)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.CachingMetadataReaderFactory.getMetadataReader(CachingMetadataReaderFactory.java:123)
    at org.springframework.context.annotation.ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.scanCandidateComponents(ClassPathScanningCandidateComponentProvider.java:429)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unsupported class file major version 64
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:196)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:177)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:163)
    at org.springframework.asm.ClassReader.<init>(ClassReader.java:284)
    at org.springframework.core.type.classreading.SimpleMetadataReader.getClassReader(SimpleMetadataReader.java:57)
    ... 19 more
```

Can someone please tell me how can I resolve the error?

Answer (score 3):

Based on the speculation in the exception information, this may be due to the incompatibility between the Java version you are using and the Java version used to compile "App.class". In this case, you need to ensure that you are using a Java runtime environment (JRE) or development tool that is compatible with the Java version used when compiling the code.